# Remove the "finance" and "money" tags and prevent their use in the future

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags

To the attention of Stack Exchange Inc. staff:

We've got a couple of tags on the site which are redundant / intrinsic:

- [finance](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/finance), currently on 31 questions.
- [money](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/money), currently on 3 questions.

I believe those tags are unnecessary, since the site topic itself is *Personal Finance and Money*.  Can we please remove those tags and have them blacklisted so they can't be used again?  We'd like to encourage new users to select more specific tags for their questions.  FWIW, I looked in the moderator tools but found I can only merge tags and create synonyms, neither of which is appropriate for these two cases.

Also, if possible, please blacklist the tag [personal-finance](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/personal-finance) too, since it has come up before.  There aren't currently any questions that use that tag, but we'd like to prevent its use for the same reason as the two above.  Thank you.

Comment: Agreed.  We don't need those.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These have been burned and blacklisted (as intrinsic tags).

Please care for [the widows and orphans](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/untagged).